# TFS client QueryHistory - get the earliest changeset

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, tfs-sdk

How shall I structure the arguments of versionControlServer QueryHistory to return the earliest changeset of a specified source location?

Perhaps, there is another way other than QueryHistory?

Comment: What TFS SDK & Server version do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query all changes in path returning 1 result, starting from lowest changeset.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff736442(v=vs.100).aspx

```
versionControlService.QueryHistory(
            path, 
            VersionSpec.Latest,
            0,
            RecursionType.Full, //look into all subfolders
            null,
            null, //version from - first
            null, //version to - latest => all
            1, //Return at maximum 1 item
            boolIncludeChanges, // Include information on changes done
            false,
            boolIncludeDLInfo,
            true //sort ascending - C1, C2, .. CLatest
)
```

Comment: Will this return all changesets since earliest?  I just want to have that one single earliest changeset returned.